# Parsing the data using shell scripting. (sort/uniq/grep)

Tags: shell, parsing, for-loop

I want to retrieve the rows with uniq count(column 4) for every  ref gene(column 7) on the basis of strand(column8 ) and tss(column 5).
If a ref gene has same number of count and it is on negative strand then keep the row with its highest tss and likewise 
If a ref gene has same number of count and it is on positive strand then keep the row with its lowest tss

I am working on the dat of format:

```
CHR TSS-25bp    TSS+25bp    count   tss Ensemble transcript refgene strand
chr15   79554474    79554524    2   79554499    ENSMUST00000089311  Sun2    -
chr15   79554475    79554525    2   79554500    ENSMUST00000100439  Sun2    -
chr15   79554477    79554527    2   79554502    ENSMUST00000046259  Sun2    -
chr15   79569054    79569104    1   79569079    ENSMUST00000159660  Sun2    -
chr15   79570243    79570293    4   79570268    ENSMUST00000160355  Sun2    -
chr17   44914075    44914125    2   44914100    ENSMUST00000050630  Supt3h  +
chr17   44914248    44914298    3   44914273    ENSMUST00000130623  Supt3h  +
chr17   44914319    44914369    3   44914344    ENSMUST00000127798  Supt3h  +
chr11   87551028    87551078    2   87551053    ENSMUST00000152700  Supt4h1 +
chr11   87551029    87551079    2   87551054    ENSMUST00000141169  Supt4h1 +
chr7    29099891    29099941    2   29099916    ENSMUST00000003527  Supt5h  -
chr11
78020504    78020554    3   78020529    ENSMUST00000108314  Supt6h  -
```

I would expect this in the output:

```
CHR TSS-25bp    TSS+25bp    count   tss Ensemble transcript refgene strand
chr15   79554477    79554527    2   79554502    ENSMUST00000046259  Sun2    -
chr15   79569054    79569104    1   79569079    ENSMUST00000159660  Sun2    -
chr15   79570243    79570293    4   79570268    ENSMUST00000160355  Sun2    -
chr17   44914075    44914125    2   44914100    ENSMUST00000050630  Supt3h  +
chr17   44914248    44914298    3   44914273    ENSMUST00000130623  Supt3h  +
chr11   87551028    87551078    2   87551053    ENSMUST00000152700  Supt4h1 +
chr7    29099891    29099941    2   29099916    ENSMUST00000003527  Supt5h  -
chr11   78020504    78020554    3   78020529    ENSMUST00000108314  Supt6h  -
```

So far I have this ,

```
#!/bin/bash

example=Workbook4.txt
for gene in `cut -f7 example | uniq`
   do
   sign=`grep $gene example | cut -f8 | uniq`
   for count in `grep $gene example | cut -f4 | sort | uniq`
   do
      if [ "$sign" == "-" ]
      then
      grep $gene example | grep $count example | sort -k5 | head -1 ----
      else
      grep $gene example | grep $count example | sort -k5 | tail -1 ----
   done
   break
done
```

I am not sure about the one in bold. It would be nice if you can help me solving this.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to give your desired output:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {print; next} 
    {key = $4 SUBSEP $7 SUBSEP $8}
    !(key in line) || ($8 == "-" && $5 > tss[key]) || ($8 == "+" && $5 < tss[key]) {
        line[key] = $0
        tss[key] = $5
    }
    END {for (key in line) print line[key]}
' file
```

```
CHR TSS-25bp    TSS+25bp    count   tss Ensemble transcript refgene strand
chr11   78020504    78020554    3   78020529    ENSMUST00000108314  Supt6h  -
chr15   79569054    79569104    1   79569079    ENSMUST00000159660  Sun2    -
chr15   79554477    79554527    2   79554502    ENSMUST00000046259  Sun2    -
chr17   44914248    44914298    3   44914273    ENSMUST00000130623  Supt3h  +
chr17   44914075    44914125    2   44914100    ENSMUST00000050630  Supt3h  +
chr15   79570243    79570293    4   79570268    ENSMUST00000160355  Sun2    -
chr11   87551028    87551078    2   87551053    ENSMUST00000152700  Supt4h1 +
chr7    29099891    29099941    2   29099916    ENSMUST00000003527  Supt5h  -
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: what happens to the code if I change the logic.I am now interested to retrieve those hits where each ref gene(column 7) has max count(column 4). if the count appears to be same for that particular gene, then keep the one with lowest tss(column 5) if its + ( column 8) and keep the one with highest tss(column 5) if its -(column8).

Comment: Flippantly, if you change the logic, the code will have to change too. Are there parts of my answer that you don't understand? If we address that, you should be able to alter the code yourself. "Teach a man to fish ..."

Comment: Its just that I haven't used such big awk commands. And never thought we could also set variables SUBSEP this way.